# What is secure to remove from GNOME Desktop => GNOME

Tags: fedora, gnome, package-management, gnome3

Days ago I was playing with Gnome 3 and Cinnamon and I decide after a few test to keep Cinnamon and remove Gnome. The problem is I don't know if it's secure to remove everything marked as installed under the group `GNOME Desktop => GNOME` since I don't know if those packages are used in any other application or maybe by Cinnamon.

What's the best and secure way to remove Gnome 3 completely? What or how would you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The packages are grouped in the groups, that can be installed and removed together. Running

```
dnf group list
```

should tell you the names of available groups and one of them should be something like `gnome-desktop-environment`. Removing it should do the job:

```
dnf group remove gnome-desktop-environment
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fedora, you could also consider a clean install of a "spin" available at: https://spins.fedoraproject.org/