# Safely uninstalling GNOME desktop environment on Fedora 29

Tags: fedora, gnome, dnf

This question is similar to [What is secure to remove from GNOME Desktop => GNOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304053/what-is-secure-to-remove-from-gnome-desktop-gnome) (but not a duplicate).

I want to remove the GNOME desktop environment. Running the proposed command in this question does not work on Fedora 29.

```
$ sudo dnf group remove gnome-desktop-environment
Warning: Group 'gnome-desktop-environment' is not installed.
Error: No groups marked for removal.
```

I noticed there is a group called `gnome-desktop` instead.

However, `sudo dnf group remove gnome-desktop` lists hundreds (all?) of installed packages for removal. It includes packages that are not at all related to GNOME (such as `lib*`, `plasma-*`, `texlive-*`, ...). I fear that running this command will force me to do a full re-install of the system.

Is there a *safe* way to remove GNOME's desktop environment from Fedora 29 that leaves me with a functioning KDE install?

I just want to reclaim some disk space (not all of it..)

Comment: My general experience is that it is difficult and risky to remove a desktop environment. It is usually easier (and faster) to backup the files that you want to keep and make a fresh installation and avoid adding things that you don't want. After the installation you can copy the files that you backed up into your fresh system.

Comment: In theory it should work. I would suggest backup first and if you have any problems reinstall kde and if that fails reinstall with the kde spin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can actually remove and install packages in the same operation, with `dnf swap`. And since the option takes groups as well as just single package names, you can switch one for another very simply:

```
dnf swap @gnome-desktop @kde-desktop
```

Comment: I did this recently on F33 and noticed that sddm was not installed; I had to install it myself afterward.

Comment: On Fedora 37 this is blocked since /etc/dnf/protected.d/fedora-workstation.conf contains gnome-shell. I have provided an answer with steps to safely set aside the file but still have NetworkManager in protected.d/ in a different new file, among other necessary steps.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answer point out, you can remove all of GNOME with `# dnf group remove gnome-desktop`. This will delete most of the packages even not related to GNOME itself (Xorg for example).

However if you just want to switch from one DE without complete reinstall, you can install other environment with e.g. `# dnf groupinstall kde-desktop`. This will bring back X and all the nessesary packages as in fresh Fedora spin.

One annoying little thing I found is that you have to reinstall packages like `chromium` using dnf. They will keep their configs though, so it wasn't a huge deal for me.

Comment: Better to do `dnf swap @gnome-desktop @kde-desktop`.

Comment: Didn't know that command @MichaelHampton. Seems like a neat option!

Comment: @MichaelHampton That can be a separate answer

Comment: @MichaelHampton I guess your answer should be the accepted answer here. Can you post it as such so I can accept it? Thanks to SanChaez as well!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably no a satisfying answer, but I don't think so. I recently tried to remove gnome from Fedora 29 to switch to i3. After setting the window manager up, I used `$ sudo dnf group remove gnome-desktop` to 'just' get rid of gnome and I wasn't even able to start up an xserver afterwards. As you said, `$ dnf group remove gnome-desktop-environment` seems to be obsolete. [I found this thread to be interesting, too](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/99ovox/remove_gnome_on_fedora_28/).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I ended up reinstalling the KDE Plasma edition instead. By the way, you should use comments instead of answers if you have information to add but can't solve the question. Answers are for answers only (hence the name), which is why you received a few downvotes I imagine.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I would have done that, but I don't have 50 reputation on `Unix+Linux` so I couldn't comment. It's unfortunate that most people just down-vote without considering new contributors on a StackExchange site. I had this same problem a few times with Fedora, so I wanted to share my experience, just in case someone might come across this question!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do this in Fedora 37 to switch to Cinnamon, and I have provided a similar one that should work for KDE below. You can replace that with another name found via `dnf grouplist --hidden -v` if neither switching to KDE nor Cinnamon. You must be in a text-mode tty (Such as by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 or whichever F key is non-graphical) since it removes gdm (and switches to lightdm)!

If you can stuck and have no graphical login screen, press Ctrl+Alt+F3 or another unused terminal and `sudo dnf install sddm` and `sudo systemctl enable sddm` (or lightdm if desired for Cinnamon) as per the steps below.

I suggest saving this as a script to your home directory (~) since you will not have a GUI and cannot easily read this page on the same computer (install lynx browser if you get really stuck).

Any updates to the KDE (below) and Cinnamon versions of this script will be at https://github.com/poikilos/linux-preinstall.

- KDE version: `wget -O ~/swap-gnome-to-kde.fedora.sh https://github.com/Poikilos/linux-preinstall/raw/master/everyone/optional/swap-gnome-to-kde.fedora.sh`
- Cinnamon version: `wget -O ~/swap-gnome-to-cinnamon.fedora.sh https://github.com/Poikilos/linux-preinstall/raw/master/everyone/optional/swap-gnome-to-cinnamon.fedora.sh`

Before choosing whether to continue, accept license including the disclaimer: https://github.com/Poikilos/linux-preinstall/blob/master/license.txt

Before doing any of this:

- save all of your work and close all GUI programs and logout (**all
  GUI applications in all TTYs will close** when switching to a
  different desktop manager!)
- do the wget command above of your choice
- as stated, go to text mode (such as Ctrl+Alt+F2 or whatever tty is non-graphical) not a GUI Terminal application.

```
echo "This script was not tested with KDE. Only the Cinnamon version was tested."
echo "If you're not sure what you're doing or are in a GUI Terminal application press Ctrl+C to cancel!"
echo "5 seconds left to cancel..."
sleep 5
sudo dnf install -y sddm
sudo mkdir /etc/dnf/protected.d-unprotected-by-linux-preinstall
sudo mv /etc/dnf/protected.d/fedora-workstation.conf /etc/dnf/protected.d-unprotected-by-linux-preinstall/
# ^ has NetworkManager & gnome-shell, but KDE uses NetworkManager:
echo "NetworkManager" | sudo tee /etc/dnf/protected.d/cinnamon-fedora-workstation-linux-preinstall.conf
sudo dnf groupremove "GNOME desktop Environment"
echo "Only say 'y' to the following if you're really sure and you are in a text-mode tty, not a GUI terminal!"
# Remove extras that will block gnome-shell uninstall:
sudo dnf remove "gnome-shell-*"
# swap avoids removing packages that both use:
sudo dnf swap gnome-shell @kde-desktop-environment
sudo systemctl enable sddm
```

Please let me know your successes or failures or submit a pull request on the repo.

Comment: Only thing I want to notice is that at some point during the runtime my screen goes blank. This is okay, just switch away and back to it: `Ctrl+Alt+F5` and then `Ctrl+Alt+F4`, for instance.