# Fedora - How to free up space?

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, memory, gui

How to free up space at fedora by removing GUI and dialoge related pkgs?

for example:
I'm looking for something like this but with `dnf`:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove libx11-6 libwayland-client0
```

Comment: Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483692

Comment: Also this could help, https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5026871