# What is the difference between @kde-desktop and @kde-desktop-environment groups in fedora

Tags: fedora, desktop-environment

I'm currently using gnome 40.x but I feel that it's not for me, I want a more feature rich DE so I want to move to KDE Plasma. While reading how to switch DEs I found [this question in unix & linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483692/safely-uninstalling-gnome-desktop-environment-on-fedora-29) and [this entry in the fedora docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/switching-desktop-environments/), however it was taken from the wiki and says that it could be outdated which made me doubt.

My question is: What's the difference between `dnf install @kde-desktop` and `dnf install @kde-desktop-environment`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Default is : `dnf grouplist` to decide the "KDE" name for that Fedora version. ....... Install KDE, example : `# dnf groupinstall "KDE Plasma Workspaces"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*KDE (K Desktop Environment) (kde-desktop)* is a *group* which means it is a list of packages, in this case a list of packages that makes the default KDE package "selection" in Fedora.

*KDE Plasma Workspaces (kde-desktop-environment)* is an *environment* which means it is a list of groups, which includes *kde-desktop* and other groups needed for a working Fedora with KDE. You can use `dnf group info kde-desktop-environment` to see list of groups in this environment:

```
Mandatory Groups:
   Administration Tools
   Common NetworkManager Submodules
   Core
   Dial-up Networking Support
   Fonts
   Guest Desktop Agents
   Hardware Support
   Input Methods
   KDE (K Desktop Environment)
   Multimedia
   Printing Support
   Standard
   base-x
 Optional Groups:
   3D Printing
   Cloud Management Tools
   Firefox Web Browser
   KDE Applications
   KDE Educational applications
   KDE Multimedia support
   KDE Telepathy
   LibreOffice
```

Mandatory groups will be installed automatically if you install *kde-desktop-environment*, optional groups only if you use `--with-optional`.

As you can see *kde-desktop-environment* also includes things like Network Manager, multimedia support (codecs) and other useful stuff. This is useful when doing a fresh installation -- the installer install just the environment which depends on everything needed for a working Fedora system.

In your case (installing an additional DE) you can install only *kde-desktop* because the other "core" groups are already installed on your system (brought in by the GNOME *workstation-product-environment* which you already have).

Comment: What a nice and concise answer, thanks!